# Tracking cursor location during drag events?

Tags: macos, cocoa, objective-c++, nstrackingarea

I have an application that is using Apple's [NSTrackingArea](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html) API to handle `mouseEntered`, `mouseMoved` and `mouseExited` events by calling `NSView::addTrackingArea`. This generally works well, except I would like to be able to track the location of the cursor on the screen during drag events.

Is there a way to subscribe to an NSView's events to determine the location of the cursor during mouse drag events?

My current code snippet:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCallback:(LocationUpdateCallback)callback
                         andView:(NSView*)nsView {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    _callback = std::move(callback);
    constexpr NSTrackingAreaOptions kTrackingOptions =
        NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited |
        NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow | NSTrackingInVisibleRect |
        NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag;
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea =
        [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:NSZeroRect
                                     options:kTrackingOptions
                                       owner:self
                                    userInfo:nil];
    _trackingArea.reset(trackingArea);
    [nsView addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
...
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
...
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
...
}
```

Comment: Is your view the dragging source or destination?

Comment: Could be either, I suppose. I just want to know where the actual cursor is on the screen at all times. During drag events the cursor still renders, just the tracking area API doesn't update the mouse location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to track mouse movement on macOS independent of my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71411170/is-there-a-way-to-track-mouse-movement-on-macos-independent-of-my-app)

Comment: Oh awesome! I'll give that a try and report back when I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that the NSTrackingArea API just doesn't support finding the mouse location, and used Willeke's suggestion to use an event monitor for drag events. Adding the below code snippet produces the behavior I desired:

```objectivec
    NSEvent* (^mouseDragged)(NSEvent*) = ^NSEvent*(NSEvent* event) {
      // Handle the mouse dragged event.
      ...
      return event;
    };

    const NSEventMask drag_mask = NSEventMaskLeftMouseDragged |
                                  NSEventMaskRightMouseDragged |
                                  NSEventMaskOtherMouseDragged;
    _monitor_id = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:drag_mask
                                                        handler:mouseDragged];
```